# Android keyboard blocking app components

Tags: xml, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="151dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/Welcome"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWelcome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/SignUp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnContinue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/Continue" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnContinue"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your email" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on the edit text to give some input, the keyboard opens up and blocks the button i.e   when the keyboard is displayed on the screen I cant see the button below the EditText.

I tried searching online but I found was to use these: 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" but none served the purpose.

I am learning Android on my own so any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" on the EditText(s) in question?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#Flags

Comment: hi @Snowlnferno..thank you for the reply..that is not what I intent to do in my application..I want the keyboard below my app i.e when I click on the EditText, the keyboard should not hide the button in the app...I want to see the button also when the keyboard is on the screen....but your link helped me to learn 2 new things..so thanks for the link too.